# How can I extract structured data from market flyers to csv?

Tags: python, c#, pdf, extract, ocr

I want to extract product name, price and discounted price from market flyers ( pdf )

I tried with iron ocr using c# to convert the pdf and create an algorithm to recover the data but the ocr doesn't always work correctly and sometimes it changes the order of data extraction. I tried using the adobe extract api but again not all the data is extracted and there are many errors. I also tried with some python libraries like PyPDF2 but again with no success. Is there a way to do this thing?

I'm trying with this one (Data to extract is only for products with price so in this case I want to extract data from page 10):
https://ipercoop.volantinopiu.com/volantino1373400pv14.html?utm_source=cooplombardia.promoipercoop.it&utm_medium=referra

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: _"Is there a way to do this thing?"_ - depends. And it highly depends on the input how much effort you need to put into it. So, please begin by specifying what kind of PDF you are dealing with. If you have no other option than to OCR the PDF, you need to come up with extraction algorithms. In that case: expect this to be non-trivial and relatively high maintainance. Also, you can throw "100%" expectations out the window, then.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.